# Practical Limits of Configuring WLAN SSIDs via Group Policy on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy, wifi

Is there a practical limit to the number of SSIDs that can be configured on a single WLAN profile via [Group Policy on Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg266419.aspx)? I am thinking about hundreds of SSIDs in a single WLAN profile.

Background info:
We are deploying a fleet of 4G mobile hotspots with unique SSIDs and passwords on them. We would like to use Group Policy to limit WiFi on our Windows 7 laptops, so that they can only connect to these pre-authorized corporate mobile hotspots, as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg266419.aspx). All of the SSIDs are configured to begin with the same prefix, but it appears that Group Policy on Windows 7 requires us to specify each unique SSID individually. That's fine, but wondering if configuring hundreds of unique SSIDs will have some negative effect on performance, or the user experience in any way. Most users will only have a password configured on their personally assigned hotspot, so if any of the others come within range they will hopefully not try to connect since a password will not have been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined limit on SSIDs per WLAN profile for XP and Windows 7 appears to be 256, per the version 1 WLANProfile XML schema defined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

With Windows 8.1 (version 2 of the XML schema) it will allow up to 10,000 SSIDs per profile, as noted here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn408663.aspx